# Why is the strict topology important for multiplier algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am reading the paper "REPRESENTATION AND INDEX THEORY
FOR TOEPLITZ OPERATORS" by Gerald Murphy and came across this passage:

[image]

I was wondering why we care about the strict topology or why is it important for multiplier algebra. So I know how these are defined but I've never understood why we should use it. Am I supposed to assume we are talking about the strict topology every time I see the multiplier algebra?

Now for this specific example given below for the Toeplitz matrix, why is it better to identify the operators on Hardy space with the multiplier algebra when talking about convergence?

Comment: Perhaps I can answer your questions with questions:  In functional analysis, why do we care about the weak$^*$-topology, or why is it important for dual spaces?  Do we always talk about the weak$^*$-topology every time we see the dual space?

Comment: Now to attempt to answer this without questions (and in full disclosure without having read the paper), the strict topology on $\mathcal{B}(H^2)=M(\mathcal{K}(H^2))$ is not the only topology where we have this convergence.  It is just one that the author chose to mention here, perhaps because these notions are important elsewhere in this paper.  
As far as when you are supposed to assume convergence is with respect to the strict topology, the author *should* always be clear about the topology when they mention convergence.

Comment: thank you for the questions. As far as I can tell, weak* topologies are important because weaker notions of convergence work in the weak * topology even when they fail to converge in the norm topology. Then, for something like PDE, one can use a variety of compactness methods to extract subsequences and show that such sequences even converge in the norm topology to give us solutions. So ultimately, we still care more about the norm topology, but these other topologies gives us a way to get there. Is that roughly correct?

Comment: That's correct.  Moreover, I could not have said it better myself.